# Buy Music Intent

Tags: android, mp3

I know there probably isn't a standard intent for "buy song", but does anyone know if there is one for a specific android music store such as Amazon MP3 or 7 Digital? On the iPhone Apple provides an API that let's you link users of your application to the iTunes store. I'm working on an Android app that has a list of songs and I want to be able to send users off to a store to buy the song just like I do on iOS.

Comment: Have you happened to come across any solution so far ?

Answer (score 0):

[This XDA developers line](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1026402) explains it well.